# A [chave-estrangeira] e a [foreign-key] são a mesma chave?

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tag-específica

Encontrei hoje duas tags que parecem representar a mesma coisa:

[chave-estrangeira](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chave-estrangeira) - 74 perguntas

> Usa-se normalmente para descrever o vínculo entre tabelas em bancos de dados, como por exemplo o MySQL

[foreign-key](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foreign-key) - 45 perguntas

> Chaves estrangeiras (FK) são um recurso de integridade de dados de bancos de dados relacionais (e SQL). Use essa tag para perguntas que tenham relação direta com chaves estrangeiras, NÃO USE só porque sua tabela possui uma chave estrangeira.

[chave-estrangeira](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chave-estrangeira) e [foreign-key](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foreign-key) - 2 perguntas

Elas são de fato a mesma coisa?

- Se sim, faz sentido criar um sinônimo?
- Se não, como explicar melhor a diferença na Recomendação de Uso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As tags tem o mesmo significado, portanto, foram mescladas.

- A tag principal é [chave-estrangeira](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chave-estrangeira), e foi aplicada em todas as questões mencionadas, obedecendo o critério de priorização da Língua Portuguesa.
- a tag [foreign-key](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foreign-key) virou um sinônimo da referida tag.